# How to show only enabled filters in opencart?

Tags: php, json, opencart, opencart-module

I am new to open cart and am trying to integrate some data from an opencart website on android platform . I need to implement the filters where only the filters that have "enable on phone" option checked from the admin panel need to be displayed.
On firing a query to fetch the list of filters I get some data from the modules in improper JSON format.now i am unable to figure out a way to list only the enabled filters and pass it to android with a custom api.
The query I used is

`select module_data from oc_journal2_modules where module_id=54`

where module_data is the field i am getting the information about the filter data and module_id is the id to the filter module. however the data i am getting is in improper JSON format thus I might need to write a custom function for fetching only the enabled filters from the `attribute` section in the `module_data`. 
Is there a more appropriate way to fetch the enabled filters? as my method might make the Api slow.
Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best example for your Question which really help to sort out things for your Query.

In Opencart open below file:

```
catalog/controller/extension/module/filter.php
```

In that file search for below line:

```
$filter_groups = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryFilters($category_id);
```

Around line no. 49

This will search in

```
catalog/model/catalog/category.php file
```

find `getCategoryFilters` function in this file.

You can check Db query in this function.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT filter_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_filter WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");
```

After that they store results in array. And create proper array with only necessary data.

Same way you can create your custom function and first set your data properly in array and then Pass it to JSON.

Hope will be work !!

Comment: Already tried but the issue persists ...Although Thanks for trying.

Comment: This data about enabled filters needs to be sent to an android app thus we have also tried creating a different API for the same but issue persists.